# Rails subquery reduce amount of raw SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models: `Post` and `Vote`. I want a make a simple query:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM votes
   WHERE votes.id = posts.id) AS vote_count
FROM posts
```

I am wondering what's the best way to do it in activerecord DSL. My goal is to minimize the amount of SQL I have to write.

I can do `Post.select("COUNT(*) from votes where votes.id = posts.id as vote_count")`

Two problems with this:

1. Raw SQL. Anyway to write this in DSL?
2. This returns only attribute `vote_count` and not "*" + vote_count. I can append `.select("*")` but I will be repeating this every time. Is there an much better/DRY way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need that subquery? It is executed once for each row and causes huge performance issue. Don't you prefer JOIN instead? `SELECT posts.*, COUNT(votes.id) FROM posts LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.id GROUP BY posts.id, posts.title`

Comment: @skalee Unless you are using old version of an SQL db from the 90s, it's smart enough to recognize and optimze the query. In my tests, doing it via JOIN or subquery both take equal amounts of time, except a subquery is more clear/readable (but that's just my opinion). Regardless, my point is there's no performance issue with using subquery.

Comment: IMO in this particular case join is more readable, however I understand your question is more general and applies to other queries as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to reduce amount of SQL, you can split that query into smaller two end execute them separately. For instance, the votes counting part could be extracted to query:

```
SELECT votes.id, COUNT(*) FROM votes GROUP BY votes.id;
```

which you may write with ActiveRecord methods as:

```
Vote.group(:id).count
```

You can store the result for later use and access it directly from Post model, for example you may define `#votes_count` as a method:

```
class Post
  def votes_count
    @@votes_count_cache ||= Vote.group(:id).count
    @@votes_count_cache[id] || 0
  end
end
```

(Of course every use of cache raises a question about invalidating or updating it, but this is out of the scope of this topic.)

But I strongly encourage you to consider yet another approach.

I believe writing complicated queries like yours with ActiveRecord methods — even if would be possible — or splitting queries into two as I proposed earlier are both bad ideas. They result in extremely cluttered code, far less readable than raw SQL. Instead, I suggest introducing query objects. IMO there is nothing wrong in using raw, complicated SQL when it's hidden behind nice interface. See: M. Fowler's [P of EAA](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) and Brynary's post on [Code Climate Blog](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/).

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this with no additional SQL at all - consider using the Rails counter_cache feature.

If you add an integer `votes_count` column to the `posts` table, you can get Rails to automatically increment and decrement that counter by changing the `belongs_to` declaration in Vote to:

```
belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
```

Rails will then keep each Post updated with the number of votes it has.  That way the count is already calculated and no sub-query is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this, however, I can't change the database schema (unfortunately). Even if I could, there are some constraints I want to apply in the subquery's where clause depending on the request so that wouldn't work out. (I didn't specify those in the question to keep it simple)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create mysql view and just map it to new AR model. It works similar way to table, you just need to specify with set_table_name "your_view_name"....maybe on DB level it will work faster and will be automatically re-calculating.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon [postgres_ext](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem which [adds support](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/blob/master/docs/querying.md) for Common Table Expressions in Arel and ActiveRecord which is exactly what you asked.  Gem is not for SQLite, but perhaps some portions could be extracted or serve as examples.